# Asterisk - Goto different step in dialplan if user not exist in mysql

Tags: mysql, real-time, asterisk

I'm trying to make dialplan with condition based on mysql response. What I want to achieve is when user call to his voicemail script to check if there are any messages left to him/her. If no messages goto other menu or another menu.

So I have this simple shell script check.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check if user has any messages left to him

count=$(mysql -u mysql -pMYPASS -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx asterisk -se "select count(mailboxuser) from voicemessages where mailboxuser=8785;")

if [ $count -gt 0 ]
then
     //echo " greater that 0 "
else
     //echo " lower than 0 "
fi
```

And the dialplan so far

```
[internal]
exten => 119,1,Set(CHANNEL(language)=en)
same => n, System(check.sh ${CALLERID})
same => n,VoicemailMain(${CALLERID(num)}@VoiceMail)
same => n,Hangup
```

When I call to 119 I see in console this

> -- Executing [119@internal:1] Set("SIP/8785-00000058", "CHANNEL(language)=en") in new stack
>
> -- Executing [119@internal:2] System("SIP/8785-00000058", "check.sh 8785") in new stack
>
> -- Executing [119@internal:3] VoiceMailMain("SIP/8785-00000058", "8785@VoiceMail") in new stack

With the query I just want to check if greater than 0. If is greater this means that the user has 1+ messages. Question is how to grab the response and construct properly if/then/gotoif condition in this dialplan. First time dealing with this and I'm not sure how to make it.

When I run it in console I've got response like this which is correct

```
*CLI> !/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/check.sh
 lower than 0
```

Also is this the correct way of doing this or there is some other way?

**Update**:

Now I have this in my `func_odbc.conf`

```
[EXIST]
dsn=asterisk
readsql=SELECT COUNT(mailboxuser) FROM voicemessages WHERE mailboxuser='${SQL_ESC(${ARG1})}'
```

Then this in my extension

```
[internal]

exten => 119,1,Set(CHANNEL(language)=en)
same => n,GotoIf($[${ODBC_EXIST(${CALLERID(num)})}]?${test:4},1:${MAINMENU:3},1)
same => n,VoicemailMain(${CALLERID(num)}@VoiceMail)
same => n,Hangup


[test]
exten => _[a-z].,1,Set(SAFE_EXTEN=${FILTER(0-9,${EXTEN})})
```

When I call with number which EXIST in DB I've got infinity loop which is bellow.. According to how I understand this I should see context `[test]` in console output, right? What I've messed here?

> -- Executing [119@internal:1] Set("SIP/8785-00000061", "CHANNEL(language)=en") in new stack
>
> -- Executing [119@internal:2] GotoIf("SIP/8785-00000061", "0?,1:,1") in new stack
>
> -- Goto (internal,119,1)
>
> -- Executing [119@internal:1] Set("SIP/8785-00000061", "CHANNEL(language)=en") in new stack
>
> -- Executing [119@internal:2] GotoIf("SIP/8785-00000061", "0?,1:,1") in new stack
>
> -- Goto (internal,119,1)
>
> -- Executing [119@internal:1] Set("SIP/8785-00000061", "CHANNEL(language)=en") in new stack
>
> -- Executing [119@internal:2] GotoIf("SIP/8785-00000061", "0?,1:,1") in new stack
>
> -- Goto (internal,119,1)

Answer (score 1):

System command not return anything to asterisk.

You have use AGI interface or(MUCH better) use func_ODBC to check user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you mean that is better to use query directly in dialplan instead?

Comment: There is example in func_odbc.conf `readsql=SELECT location FROM presence WHERE id='${SQL_ESC(${ARG1})}'` if I try to use this can you show me an example of goto different contexts depending of the result?

Comment: Thanks for the example. I've updated my question with what I've tried from the link above and the error I got. Can you tell what is wrong now?

Comment: Debug is offtopic on SO. You have do it yourself.

Comment: Your dialplan have loop. You are asking to debug it. It is not a question. Please go asterisk.org forum with such issues or hire someone.